# List course categories on home page moodle

Tags: moodle

I am new in Moodle. How can I list / get all course categories?
I want to display course categories at front end. I tried with custom queries but my lesser experience I am not able to get it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if you mean this, but you can go to '***Site administration***' --> '***Front Page***' --> '***Front page settings***' menu.

There, you can select the value 'List of categories' in 'Front Page' and 'Front page items when logged in' sections.

In addition, you can indicate the nesting levels (or unlimited) to show the categories and subcategories in 'Maximum category depth' section (see attached image).

[Moodle FrontPage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ICHUz.png)